# Should I remove my question?

Tags: discussion, questions

- I have asked question before 4 days ago [Magento2 Admin dashboard
  chart is broken in my all Projects](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/266444/magento2-admin-dashboard-chart-is-broken-in-my-all-projects)
- I think that was temporary problem,now it is working fine.

so please tell me Now what should do with question?
May be I cant delete it because it has answers so i request it by generating flag.

> There is problem in both situation

**If Delete :**

- I lost my reputation from this question I gained(not sure)

**If not Delete :**

- User think I may mislead to him
- User may down-vote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to delete your question.

If your issue has resolved suddenly magically that it not means your question, it not right.

The answers posted for your question might help other people in future.

So, please don't delete the question and put commit like that `"MY problem is suddenly fixed automatically"`.